# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND but data is loaded

Tags: java, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrVhd.png)I have some error. this is my code.
File html:

```
<div ng-controller="newsCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="x in news">

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="newsContent">{{x.content}}</div>
        <div class="newsImage"><img src="../image/{{x.image}}" alt="vinfast oto"></div>
        <div class="newsTitle">
          <h2>{{x.title}}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

File app.js:

```
app.controller("newsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/EX11_29112018_spring_restful/news"
  }).then(function (response) {
    $scope.news = response.data;
  })
});
```

Html in views folder, app.js in js folder, they are in webapp folder. My image is loaded, but I have this error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND;
How to fix it.

Comment: Did you trt with ng-src as `<img ng-src="string"></img>`?

Comment: yep, thanks so much

Comment: did it work with the change??

Comment: yes, I have try and it worked

Comment: i will put as answer for future for others, ok! pls accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngSrc` directive solves this problem. So change

```
<img src="../image/{{x.image}}" alt="vinfast oto">
```

to correct way as:

```
<img ng-src="../image/{{x.image}}"></img>
```

Find more about `ngSrc` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).